# How can you get the actual MonitorID to change display settings

Tags: c#, .net, windows, operating-system, system

I've been having issues trying to obtain the correct/true monitorID. Everything online is about obtaining the devicename from Screen object or getting monitor information through DISPLAY_DEVICE. I have code in place that can make monitors primary or not, the problem is getting the correct and true monitor ID. Apparently, windows changes the monitor ID meaning your "Display1" could be 0,1,2 etc. When I was testing this, this is what I found:

Local Dev laptop: 
"Display1" was ID of 0
"Display4" (external monitor) was an ID of 3. I don't understand why it was "display 4" if I only had my laptop and an external monitor. I would think it would be "Display 2".

On a CPU (3 of them I tested it on) that has VGA and HDMI connections
"Display1" was Ian D of 1.

on another CPU "Display1" was no longer an ID of 1, but it was a completely different ID.

When I go into Display setting and click "Detect" It shows 1 and 2.

I thought maybe grabbing the devicename and substring it out to get the number and do -1 to get the true ID, but that only works on my dev laptop.

Is there any way possible to obtain the monitors correct/true ID?

Comment: From [How can I retrieve monitor information?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/668e3cf9-4e00-4b40-a6f8-c7d2fc1afd39/how-can-i-retrieve-monitor-information) - _"There is not a supported way to figure out the IDs that you referred to programmatically. It was never a design goal to provide a way for applications to label monitors with the same IDs that the screen resolution control panel uses. What is your application trying to accomplish?_" - you say you need the monitor ID to change settings - what API are you using to do that?

Comment: One application needs to load on a specific monitor and that monitor needs to be primary.  This check would help if, when the application loads and there is a screen flip where app A is on Monitor B and App B is on Monitor A the functionality that is in place to set the primary screen (if using the correct monitor id) it will set App A to Monitor A and set that primary, to correct the issue, without logging out and manually doing it. I am using the Windows API that uses:  NativeMethods.EnumDisplayDevices();
NativeMethods.EnumDisplaySettings();

Comment: Doesn't the state flag `DISPLAY_DEVICE_PRIMARY_DEVICE` returned from `EnumDisplayDevices` tell you this?

Comment: Actually, what you just said sparked an idea, and will give it a shot. I'll let you know how that goes

Comment: @stuartd Thank you for that, I needed to check what is attached and not primary and grab that ID and that so far is the true id for the monitor. Been able to switch screens back n forth, now I just need to check on the screens and make sure to only  execute that code when the screen is flipped